# Rename file using cmd

Tags: sql, sql-server

My code is like below and has to rename the file by adding timestamps.

```
declare @timestamp nvarchar(20),@rename nvarchar(500)
set @timestamp= (select convert (nvarchar(16),getdate(),127))

 set @rename='RENAME \\girishc\fullshared\Girish\Export\test.xls test'+@timestamp+'.xls'
 EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @rename
```

Its not working at my end and get

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Can you please help me here.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @Girish . . . There is not much you can do.  You can kill all Excel instances running on that computer -- and that should free the file.  But it could have undesirable side effects.

Comment: It says you or someone else already opened the file, because of that you cannot change the name.